# TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null react hooks

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to figure why I'm getting an error from my custom hook. My hook calls an api that requires a key which I have provided.

Here is what I'm working with: this is my hook fetching an api

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const useFetch = async => {
  const [response, setResponse] = React.useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?apiKey=9e48dbd7f1a346599a0bbfe8f8386484",
          {
            params: {
              q: "bitcoin"
            }
          }
        );

        setResponse(res);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return { response, error };
};
export default useFetch;
```

this is the page I'm using this hook:

```
import React from "react";
import useFetch from "../hooks/useFetch";
import "../css/Layout.scss";
import Card from "./Card";

function Layout() {
  const { response, error } = useFetch();

  console.log(error, "error");

  console.log(response);

  return (
    <div className="Layout__container">
      <div className="Layout__container__mainColumn"></div>
      <div className="Layout__container__rightColumn"> right </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

When I console.log the response, I get the result I want but when I try to map the `articles` inside the response or even `console.log(response.data);` I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null` and I don't understand why. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Initially `response` is `null`. The result of your `fetch` arrives **asynchronously**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const res = await axios.get("http...",{params: {q: "bitcoin" }});
let data = await res.json() //if the response is json
setResponse(data)
```

Looks like you need to await the response.

Answer (score 0):

The first value of response is null

```
const [response, setResponse] = React.useState(null);
```

To avoid the error you can initialize with empty array

```
const [response, setResponse] = React.useState([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

At the very first render response might be null. You need to check response first if it exists then get data from it.